# Why don't TypeScript methods require a "this" context of the type of the class?

Tags: typescript

Methods in TypeScript classes rely on having the correct `this` parameter to be type safe, and therefore should only be called in a context where `this` is of the expected type.

However, methods declared in the normal way do not require any `this` context, and can be called as free functions without error.

In this example (tested in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)), only the commented call to greet_2 would be an error.

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet1() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
    greet2(this: Greeter) {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");

let greet_1 = greeter.greet1;
let greet_2 = greeter.greet2;

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    greet_1();
    // greet_2();
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: I am tempted to raise a second question - _Why are TypeScript methods allowed to declare a "this" context incompatible with the class?_ - since it is not an error to add this third method: `greet3(this: string) { return "Hello, " + this; }` Thankfully in this case it is an error to attempt to call the method on an instance of the class.

Comment: Hmm, I just posted an [answer on this very topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711374/2887218) where I link to the relevant GitHub issues.  Does that answer this question for you?

Comment: @jcalz, yes. That does appear to be the feature I'm missing. I hope this does eventually get implemented - it seems like a surprising oversight, especially for users who have enabled `--noImplicitAny` and `--noImplicitThis`! If you'd like to add an answer like _"This did not exist in early non-strict Typescript, and a strict mode that behaves like this was considered but then dropped due to backward compatibility and compiler performance concerns - GitHub ticket here: (link)"_ I'd be happy to accept and upvote it.