# Typescript Types and .bind

Tags: javascript, typescript, events

I'm starting to delve into generics and have a generic event class that looks like this

```
export interface Listener < T > {
  (event: T): any;
}

export class EventTyped < T > {
  //Array of listeners
  private listeners: Listener < T > [] = [];

  Attach(listener: Listener < T > ) {
    this.listeners.push(listener);
  }

  Emit(event: T) {
    this.listeners.forEach(listener => listener(event));
  }
}
```

I create my event like this `onPageSizeSelected = new EventType<PageSizeSelector>();`

My listeners signature is this `PageSizeSelectedHandler(event:Event,object:PageSizeSelector)`.

When I go to attach the event like this `pageSizeSelector.onPageSizeSelected.Attach(this.PageSizeSelectedHandler.bind(this))` no error is thrown. 
When the handler is attached like this `pageSizeSelector.onPageSizeSelected.Attach(this.PageSizeSelectedHandler)`. It immediately picks up the the method signature is incorrect and has too many parameters.

What is bind doing that typescript can't correctly infer the method signature? How can I safely keep my `this` and have my event strongly typed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you want is for the compiler to catch bound methods having the wrong number of parameters and you don't care about the `this` context, you can just make sure to enable [the `--strictBindCallApply` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply):

```
class StringListeningClassThing {
  myString = "hey";
  oneParam(x: string) {
    return x + this.myString;
  }
  twoParams(x: number, y: string) {
    return x.toFixed(2) + y + this.myString;
  }
}

const onPageSizeSelected = new EventTyped<string>();
const stringListenerThingy = new StringListeningClassThing();

onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.twoParams); // error
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.twoParams.bind(stringListenerThingy)); // error
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.oneParam.bind(stringListenerThingy)); // okay
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.twoParams.bind(stringListenerThingy, 2)); // okay
```

This might be all you need.  But there are still some type safety issues here:

---

Unfortunately TypeScript doesn't do a great job of type-checking `this` contexts automatically:

```
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.oneParam); // no error 
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.oneParam.bind({ notGood: true })); // no error
```

The fact that those are accepted means you will have runtime errors, as `stringListenerThingy`'s methods dereference a bad `this`.

There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#7968](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) to add something like a `--strictThis` compiler option which would prevent you from passing around mis-bound functions, but it hasn't yet been implemented, apparently because it would [both break lots of existing code and have a significant compiler performance impact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7689#issue-143586130).  If you want to see that implemented you might want to go to that issue and give it a  and/or describe your use case (if it is particularly compelling and not already mentioned in that issue).

If you really want to make the compiler do this checking, it *is* possible, but you will need to add [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) manually to all sorts of places in your code.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
// explicitly add void this-context to definition of Listener
export interface Listener<T> {
  (this: void, event: T): any;
}

// explicitly add class-based this-context to all methods 
class StringListeningClassThing {
  myString = "hey";
  oneParam(this: StringListeningClassThing, x: string) {
    return x + this.myString;
  }
  twoParams(this: StringListeningClassThing, x: number, y: string) {
    return x.toFixed(2) + y + this.myString;
  }
}
```

And now the above examples give the desired errors:

```
// enjoy type safety   
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.oneParam); // error 
onPageSizeSelected.Attach(
  stringListenerThingy.oneParam.bind({ notGood: true })); // error
```

So the compiler *can* enforce this stuff, but not automatically, until and unless `--strictThis` becomes a thing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/PTAEFMA8AcBsEsDG8AusCeoCGATHoA3Ae3nxQAt4BnURIgOxShQFgAoKaIgJxVHkbhuAMyyJwoADLUm9IQB4AKgD5QAb3ahQACgrUAXIRI4ANBALhGhxQEpDWeugDc7AL7t2nHn0SwsVGgBRC0ZFdGhwHCVVDTYtEABBbm4sTCJhUAQqWSEqTVBobngCLCZMmUtcw2lsyu5ogG0AXVAAXlBmlzZ8hJQUMXJtLJzuaoq5epUbdXytPSoAOmG6xegAVypB5YmbLq13brjQQIBbVG1wEJRraditOcpF7dyF4R5AgaHxoTbVZ+4LlcbLt8gcDuwQBAYAhkGhMLh8L5-FQALQAI38kVA8xRdEEkD4KCI2FgsFAJ3AFCIOBo7CRAVAAGUUEV6ABzGqyARsgDCfgCiko7JmRxO6GZrLZbVAACJyOB0DK9qAGOAAApYFInXSPQwS7mcyzcvnIwXcsyQQzZSW3WagbiUtbceigSCgADU2MeCzF+vZyoOcwA7kQNVqqDqDEyWQbxsb+VQzeyLYZ6GsTmihGZ0FaY+zbUctA6UE6XZAFkSAGLwSCRbQAJmmnswnvmPvFebZAbcHjYeOyKvoGrZ4EZ8AAXqPwLBwIgmPh2nIg8crmEIlFrdzlNoQX2GAPN+zDRMk2zMIvwMu-Ry4+yTQKhWyd10IWAUSjN3OAEICHA8rCkgk0BwJg8qwNANDyg67AMMOo4TlOM5zpECy9P0iCDIeN61Cej7oBWIZhlgJxULsoCQkI3A8NgNA4OAVDwA6OAwUOWAjmOk6MtOs7zqhfSfFhx5CKe+EoIRmrEYsaK-tognfNwInAk45FgJR1H+KAdEMUxLFwRxiE8ShaECZ2QkKXhCyqkRJwLNJ9A4LJpnyYpZGQkQADWqQAIS6Wx8GcdxyE4Hx6GYU5OHCRZYmhhJJG2TJckReZ3LoGYjauWAHmpL2FH0AAVkQmAoOEEhUFgwiUpgWi+exCFcUhvHGRh2j5IlIwiZZcjWRlEDJOptH0YxkQ1f5BlBSFnyteF7UWVZsXxfZ2hqKA9BECgADiRDUoYLJrBIrhKSpJJUMSancL2QA)

Comment: right, should've checked the docs before making an (un)educated guess ...

Comment: My compiler will not error on the second .bind. I don't mind adding the `this` as a parameter to the event handlers if that is required to gain type inference. Have you reworked your events to avoid this by any chance? I may try to do that.

Comment: Maybe you don't have something in `--strict` checking enabled?  Or are using an older compiler version?  I haven't done this myself anywhere meaningfully, though... it's quite a bit of work since you have to follow `this` context all over the place, sometimes even overriding or replacing standard library definitions 

Comment: Yeah I went and checked. My only option not true is `strictPropertyInitialization`. In your example it also seems like I can change the type of the second dosomething paramater and not ..... edit went and checked in VSCode and the correct errors appeared. Hoping VS 2019 comes out with better TS support here in April.

Comment: So it looks like I can get close to what I'm looking for by using the generic event class and having a couple different listener types like `():any` or `(event?:T)` or `(event?:T,eventArgs?:T)` and this should cover most of my use cases. Visual Studio was frustratingly not picking these types up at all while VSCode seems to be doing this quite well.

Comment: @jcalz does the newish strictBindCallApply from typescript 3.2 fix this issue for you? Just installed and the IDE was able to recognize when my bound method had the incorrect parameter types.

Comment: It seems it's somewhat implemented at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028... Can you confirm it's what you were talking about, and if so update your anwer? :-)

Comment: I re-read the question and answer and... well, it kind of looks like I answered a different question from the one asked?  Anyway I've edited it now, with the stuff at top directly relevant to the question (and it's basically just "use `--strict`") and the stuff below that highlighting how there's still an issue with `this` lurking that isn't solved by `--strictBindCallApply`. ‍♂️